# How can I pretty-print JSON using unix cmd/shell script?

Tags: json, pretty-print

I would like to align my json file into human readable format using unix cmd or any shell script. And, this should happen without installing anything (jq, json_reformat  etc.,)

I want it to transform the following:

```
{ "name": "Ram", "age": "56" }
```

.. into something like this:

```
{
    "name": "Ram",
    "age": "56"
}
```

Comment: Use [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

Comment: @axiac any other way without using jq ?

Comment: I guess you have to write a JSON parser.